# How to render three.js using node.js?

Tags: node.js, three.js

Here's an overview; My goal is to render an avatar (using `three.js`) on `node.js` (server side). Then, get the data URI scheme of the output/canvas and go from there.

The reason why I want to render it server-sided is to avoid users manipulating the render/properties of the avatar. (So they don't add their own texture, change colors, etc.)

Currently, I have this working when ran in a browser. Since I am using the `WebGLRenderer`, I can just access the `toDataURL` under `renderer.domElement` and I can go from there.

However, my issue is I do not know which renderer to use with `node.js` *and still get the data `URI` scheme*. I can not use `WebGLRenderer` because no browser exists, and as a result will give errors (document is not defined etc...) so how should I go about doing this?

Comment: why don't you do it in the browsers and lock webglrenderer so the user cannot manipulate the data?

Comment: @chriskelly can you elaborate on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `three.js` module on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/three.js